# If $\alpha $ is a root for $ x^2-2x+3=0 \implies \alpha^2-2\alpha^3=9 $

Tags: quadratics

If $\alpha $ is a root for $ x^2-2x+3=0 $, Proove that $\alpha^2-2\alpha^3=9 $

I have tried the following,

since $\alpha$ is a root, it should satisfy the equation. Hence, $$\alpha^2-2\alpha+3=0    $$

Since this equation has complex roots, other root should be the conjugate of $\alpha$, Do I need to consider this?
This looks so simple but cannot work it out further. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\alpha^2=2\alpha-3$.

$$\alpha^2-2\alpha^3=\alpha^2(1-2\alpha)=(2\alpha-3)(1-2\alpha)=-4\alpha^2+8\alpha-3=-4(2\alpha-3)+8\alpha-3=9$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;\alpha^2=2 \alpha - 3\,$, so $\,\alpha^2 - 2 \alpha^2 \alpha = (2\alpha-3)-2(2\alpha-3)\alpha=-4\alpha^2+8\alpha-3\ldots\,$

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(  2 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  + 9 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right)  \cdot  \left(  2 x  + 3 \right)    $$